# Android Facebook SDK - Share post with public

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using Facebook SDk for android for posting statuses to user's timeline and it works fine except that the posts are shared with the user's **friends** and not with the **public** which is what I need it to do. I didn't find any solution yet so I'm asking this forum.

Hope my question is clear.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the privacy setting of a feed, you can add additional parameter- `privacy` with your `/me/feed` call.

```
JSONObject privacy = new JSONObject();
privacy.put("value", "EVERYONE");
params.putString("privacy", privacy.toString());
..... //other params
..... // make the call `/me/feed`
```

[More details here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/)

#### Please Note

A user can also manually sets the privacy of an application. To check this: go to your [Facebook Settings](http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications), see what you've set your application to.

The actual privacy applied will be the **more restrictive privacy setting** between the two.

**eg.** 
If the user has set "*Only Me*" in the facebook settings, but in app you applied "*Public*", then the user's preference, i.e.  *Only Me* will be used. 

But if the user has set "*Public*" in the app settings, but in the app you applied "*Friends*", then the app's setting i.e. "*Friends*" is used, as it's more restrictive than the User's settings.

Hope that helps.